# speech recognition using HMM or MFCC

Tags: c#, c++, speech-recognition, mfcc

please help me in speech recognition using HMM (hidden markov models) or MFCC ( Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficient ) by longage c# or c++
I want to recognize word "one", "two"... to "ten")
When I say one  ===> show MessageBox write one

Answer (score 2):

You should use a toolkit for this purpose like HTK, Kaldi, etc. which are open-source or you could use a free API like Google Speech API, Microsoft Speech API (SAPI), etc.

It is not really easy to do speech recognition using HMM from scratch. BTW, MFCC is not a machine learning tool like HMM. MFCC is a method of feature extraction which is used to prepare observations for HMM training and decoding.